# How do I write a link to a static file in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, asp.net-mvc-routing

In my MVC application I have a folder full of PDF documents users should be able to view. However, my links to them don't seem to work: I get a "resource can't be found error". I'm guessing my problem has something to do with routing.

What do I need to do so that the browser just renders the documents?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `IgnoreRoute` to exclude specific paths from the routing logic. [This post](http://weblogs.asp.net/rashid/archive/2009/04/03/asp-net-mvc-best-practices-part-2.aspx#routing) has a number of useful suggestions regarding how to optimise routing.

Also ensure that permissions on the directory and PDF files it contains are correctly set - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1031876/accessing-static-content-of-an-asp-net-mvc-project-with-iis7/1035692#1035692).